# Remove the URL author of post on all comments

Tags: posts, comments

I can't manage to disable the URL of only the author's post. Here's an example : [My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faCDt.png)

As you can see, the green link is mine (the author of the post). I only want to remove that link, not other comments links.

How can I do this? I have tried altering this bit of code in functions.php, but it didn't do what I want (it's removing everyone URL, not just mine):

```
    add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'rv_remove_comment_author_link', 10, 3 );
function rv_remove_comment_author_link( $url, $author, $comment_ID ) {
    return $author;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you can do that using CSS display:none.  I can take a look, send us a link to one of the posts please.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress have  "get_comment_author_url" function to retrieve the url of the author of the current comment.

you can set it to blank using this

```
function remove_author_url( $url, $id, $commentr ) { 
    return ""; 
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', 'remove_author_url', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

aslam shikalgar you misunderstood. I don't want to get all authors of comment blank. Only the author of the post which he's commenting.